# jQuery if statement to change CSS

Tags: jquery, css, button, click, toggle

This code is about pressing the button which makes the text toggle (show/hide):

```
jQuery('Button']').click(function () {
    jQuery('#text').slideToggle('fast', function () {});      
    if (jQuery('#text').css('display') == 'block') {
        jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-top":"0px"});
        jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-bottom":"7px solid #0767B1"});            
       }
    if (jQuery('#text').css('display') == 'none') {
        jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-bottom":"0px"});
        jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-top":"7px solid #0767B1"});        
       }    
});
```

Everything works except the display:none, anyone got any idea why/how to fix  this?

Comment: There's no `else`. Also jQuery has a `.toggle()` method.

Comment: `'Button']'` is not a valid selector. Check your JavaScript console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some improvments:

- Use `.is(':visible')` to check if the element is visible
- Move the if statement inside the `callback` function of `slideToggle()`
- Merge the two css calls into a single call
- You have a typo in the first row - 'Button']'

Code:

```
jQuery('Button').click(function () {
  jQuery('#text').slideToggle('fast', function () {
    text_obj = $(this)
    if (text_obj.is(':visible')) {
      jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-top":"0px", "border-bottom":"7px solid #0767B1"});
    }
    else {
      jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css({"border-bottom":"0px", "border-top":"7px solid #0767B1"});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The typo is because of changed some names for this problem. Anyways, this worked out! Thanks in many ways.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If its the best answer, please mark it as the solution :D

Answer (score 3):

Test instead if the element is visible:

```
if (jQuery('#text').is(":visible")) {
    // something
}
else {
    // something else
}
```

Comment: @PimPeters: Well, there is no description of what "doesn't work" means in this question. Adding even a little bit of detail would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
jQuery('button').click(function () {
    jQuery('#dropdown1arrow').css(jQuery('#text').is(":visible") ? 
                  {"border-top":"0px", "border-bottom":"7px solid #0767B1"} :
                  {"border-bottom":"0px", "border-top":"7px solid #0767B1"}
                 );
});
```